# How to get standard matplotlib colours in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn

I am using python to sketch all my graphs for my thesis. I am almost done, but want to add a few violin plots to my work. Thus far I have used pyplot (or matplotlib) for all my sketches, but the matplotlib violin plot does not work with my data because there are several NaN in. Therefore I am using seaborn for the violin plots. However, the colours are different to that of matplotlib, resulting in an inconsistency in my thesis. I tried finding the hue to select in seaborn to make the colours the same as that of matplotlib, but I cannot find the information any where. Does someone know how to do this?

The code is not really applicable in this question, so I am simply attaching two figures to illustrate my problem. In conclusion, I want to get the matplotlib colours in Seaborn.

[image: Matplotlib colours.]

[image: Seaborn colours]

Comment: in the two posted plots the colors seem consistent: Blue, Orange, Green. What inconsistency are you referring to?

Comment: I believe it's `sns.color_palette("tab10")`.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki the colours are the same but they have different brightnesses. It looks odd when they are placed together in a document.

Comment: Seaborn prefers to desaturate colors used for filling. You can try `sns.violinplot(...., saturation=1)` to get the "full" colors. (By default seaborn uses `saturation=0.75`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default matplotlib color palette is `tab10`, as shown in the "Qualitative" colormaps on [this documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#qualitative). I think the easiest way to use it would be to set the global colormap to `tab10` (or use `tab20` if you have more than 10 items) using [`sns.set_palette`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_palette.html). By doing that, every seaborn figure you make in that script that uses a *discrete* colormap will use the `tab10` colormap.

Edit: As commented by @[JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc), you also need to set `saturation=1` when creating the plots. As the documentation states regarding the `saturation` parameter:

> Proportion of the original saturation to draw colors at. Large patches often look better with slightly desaturated colors, but set this to `1` if you want the plot colors to perfectly match the input color.

Example (adapted from the [`seaborn.violinplot` documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html)):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.close("all")
sns.set_palette("tab10") # or "tab20"

df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.violinplot(data=df, x="age", y="class", ax=ax, saturation=1)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: You also need `sns.violinplot(..., saturation=1)`. Also note that seaborn distinguishes between discrete and continuous colormapping. `sns.setpalette()` only influences discrete plots, not e.g. `sns.heatmap()`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `tab10` palette:

```
sns.color_palette("tab10")
```

or in your case:

```
sns.violinplot(..., palette="tab10")
```

EDIT:

You also need `saturation=1`:

```
sns.violinplot(..., palette="tab10", saturation=1)
```